# MongoDB replace array inside array w/ C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to replace the contents of 'baz.'

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("6058f722e9e41a3d243258dc"),
  "fooName" : "foo1",
  "fooCode" : 1,
  "bar" : [
    {
      "barCode" : "123",
      "barName" : "Rick's Cafe",
      "baz" : [
        {
          "bazId" : "00",
          "bazDescription" : "Ilsa"
        },
        {
          "bazId" : "21",
          "bazDescription" : "Victor"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I started with UpdateOneAsync and the filter

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> filter =
  f => f.fooCode == 1 &&
  f.Bar.Any(b => s.BarCode == "123")
```

And once I started typing the update statement

```
Builders<Foo>.Update.Set(f => ??? , newBazArray);
```

I realized I was probably doing this incorrectly.  How should I replace the array baz?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use this:

```
f => f.Bar[-1].baz
```

Where `[-1]` is equivalent to the positional operator ($) in a Mongo query.

Note that with the latest version of the MongoDB driver (I think since 2.16.0, but certainly in 2.19.0), you will get the following exception if you use `[-1]` for the positional operator:

> MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionNotSupportedException: Expression not supported: mydocumentarray.get_Item(-1) because negative indexes are not valid. To use the positional operator $ use FirstMatchingElement instead of an index value of -1.

So instead of `f => f.Bar[-1].baz`, you would now write:

```
f => f.Bar.FirstMatchingElement().baz
```

There is also `.FirstN(x)` which will update the first x (e.g. 3) matching entries, and `.AllMatchingElements()` which will update all that match.

Comment: No, the only elements available to f are fooName, fooCode, and bar.  That's what made me realize I may be on the wrong path.

Comment: Alright, I'm an idiot.  You were correct.  Take your internet points and thanks for letting me talk (type?) this out.  Don't code late at night when you're tired kids.

Comment: Using -1 to indicate the positional operator no longer works as of the 2.19.0 driver since (LINQ3 has been made the default LINQ provider, and LINQ3 [doesn't support this syntax](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-4079))

Comment: @ninjoncrak Yes, I had already updated my answer to reflect that. [Edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66773979/revisions).